# Postgresql: Using a window function to select the MAX value from a date range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to select the maximum value from within the past two years

For example if I have a table as follows:

```
|person_id | pass_or_fail | timestamp|
|----------|--------------|-----------|
|1234      | 1            | 1990-01-01|
|1234      | 0            | 1995-01-01|
|1234      | NULL         | 1995-12-12|
|6789      | 0            | 1990-01-01|
|6789      | 0            | 1991-01-01|
|6789      | 1            | 1995-01-01|
|6789      | 1            | 1996-01-01|
|6789      | 0            | 1997-01-01|
|6789      | NULL         | 1997-03-03|
```

I want to get the following from my query:

```
person_id |highest_grade_from_past_two_years | pass_or_fail | timestamp
1234      |1                                 | 1            | 1990-01-01
1234      |0                                 | 0            | 1995-01-01
1234      |0                                 | NULL         | 1995-12-12
6789      |0                                 | 0            | 1990-01-01
6789      |0                                 | 0            | 1991-01-01
6789      |1                                 | 1            | 1995-01-01
6789      |1                                 | 1            | 1996-01-01
6789      |1                                 | 0            | 1997-01-01
6789      |1                                 | NULL         | 1997-03-03
```

How could I write my window function to give me this result?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see how to write this query with window functions. Version without window :

```
SELECT t1.person_id,
       max(t2.pass_or_fail) AS highest_grade_from_past_two_years,
       t1.pass_or_fail,
       t1.timestamp
FROM t AS t1
     JOIN t AS t2 ON (
          t1.person_id = t2.person_id
          AND t2.timestamp < t1.timestamp + '2 year'::interval
          AND t2.timestamp <= t1.timestamp
     )
GROUP BY 1, 3, 4
```

Comment: The second table above is what I want my query results to look like. I am only working with one table

Comment: both tables is the same, i use it to avoid running using subquery in select statement - it run for each row separatelly

Answer (score 0):

By joining with actual year - 1 (if exists)

```
select p1.person_id, p1.pass_or_fail, p1.timestamp,
       case when coalesce(p1.pass_or_fail,0) > coalesce(p2.pass_or_fail,0) 
            then coalesce(p1.pass_or_fail,0) else coalesce(p2.pass_or_fail,0) end as highest_grade_from_past_two_years
from person p1
     left join person p2
     on p1.person_id = p2.person_id
        and extract(year from p2.timestamp) = extract(year from p1.timestamp) - 1
order by p1.person_id, p1.timestamp
```

;

Check here: http://rextester.com/BNPW52530

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an obvious way to use window functions.  A correlated subquery or lateral join would work:

```
select t.*,
       (select max(t2.pass_or_fail)
        from t t2
        where t2.person_id = t.person_id and
              t2.timestamp <= t.timestamp and
              t2.timestamp >= t.timestamp - interval '2 year'
       ) as highest_grade_from_past_two_years
from t;
```

I think the closest you can get with window functions is a range specification.  However, Postgres doesn't support the `preceding` specification with `range`.

Comment: It is not very good to put subquery in select - it run for each row separatelly.

Comment: @RomanTkachuk . . . I don't think you understand SQL as well as I do.  A correlated subquery is fine here.  It will run faster with an index on `t(person_id, timestamp, pass_or_fail)`.